# Alternativa de CSS compatível com IE7

Tags: html, css

Preciso adaptar um site para o `IE-7` em modo de compatibilidade, pesquisei algumas bibliotecas para que o `bootstrap` funciona-se, tentei o mesmo para utilizar ícones(`Font-Awesome`, `glyphicon`).

Dúvidas que possuo?

1. Como posso utilizar, os ícones no IE-7.
2. Como faço o efeito de rolagem ao clicar em um menu(rolar junto com site ao clicar nos links/ancoras).
3. Como faço para uma imagem carregar 100% em um div sem distorcer.

Segue imagem do site na versão para `chrome` e navegadores mais atuais:

[image: Exibição para navegadores atuais]
Já no IE-7 em compatibilidade está essa beleza:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Estou estudando o `CSS` para conseguir um resultado melhor, ou mais aceitável para esse cenário, apreciarei qualquer sugestão ou ajuda, segue abaixo o que tentei:

```css
.group{
   text-align:center;
   height:800px;
   z-index:1;
   top:70px;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  
  .fixed-top{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   height: 70px;
   z-index: 1000;
  }
  
  .title{
   font-weight: 700px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 50px;
   line-height: 100px;
   box-sizing: inherit;
  }
  
  #top{
  
   width:100%;
   padding-top:70px;
   text-align:center;
   border-bottom: 1px solid;
   color:white;
   margin: 0;
   background: url("https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/111/501/original/header2.jpg?1506619323") center;
   background-size: 100%;
   
  }
  
  #about{
   background-color: #e20613 !important;
   color:white;
  }
  
  img{
   height: 33%;
   width: 33%;
  }
    
/* Também incluo o Bootstrap-IE7Fix
 * Bootstrap 3 IE7 Fix v0.3
 * https://github.com/LPology/Bootstrap-IE7Fix
 */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 TRANSITIONAL//EN">
<head>
 <meta content="ie=7.0000" http-equiv="x-ua-compatible">
 <title>Inpart Saúde</title>
 <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
 <meta name="description" content="sistema inpart saúde">
 
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
 <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

</head>
<body class="bgsCover">
 <div id="wrap">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default fixed-top">
   <div class="container">
    <a href="#login" class="navbar-toggle link" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
     Acesso ao sistema
    </a> 

    <a href="#contact" class="navbar-toggle link" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
     Contatos
    </a> 
    
    <a href="#solution" class="navbar-toggle link" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
     Soluções
    </a>
    
    <a href="#services" class="navbar-toggle link" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
     Serviços
    </a>
    
    <a href="#about" class="navbar-toggle link" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
     Empresa
    </a>
    
    <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="#">
     <img alt="Inpart Saúde" src="includes/InpartSaude.png" style="width:13%">
    </a> 
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group" id="top">
   <div class="container">
    <h4 class="title">Missão & Visão</h4>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
     <h2>Integrante do GRUPO INPART SERVIÇOS, a INPART SAÚDE nasceu em 2004 com o objetivo de atender as necessidades das empresas atuantes no mercado de saúde, através da criação e disponibilização de um sistema integrado de gerenciamento de processos de cotação e compra e de informações de materiais médico-hospitalares de alto custo, baseado na Internet.</h2>
     <p>
      <a class="btn btn-lg learn-more-btn" id="btn-about" href="#about">
       Saiba mais »
      </a>
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group" id="about">
   <div class="container">
    <h4 class="title">Foco e Especialização</h4>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
     <h2>Nossa especialização objetiva promover a otimização do processo de fornecimento de materiais especiais/de alto custo, a melhoria na qualidade e agilidade de acesso às informações, fomentando a interação entre os agentes de mercado, através de módulos on-line de interface amigável, contribuindo com os processos de gestão, gerando resultados concretos.</h2>
     <p>
      <a class="btn btn-lg learn-more-btn" id="btn-services" href="#services">
       Descubra as vantagens »
      </a>
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group" id="services">
   <div class="container">
    <h4 class="title">Serviços com vantagens exclusivas</h4>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
       <h3>Tecnologia</h3>
       <p class="description">Cotação e Compras on-line em tempo real.</p>
       <p class="description">Alta tecnologia em desenvolvimento de sistemas.</p>
       <p class="description">Módulos de sistema de interface amigável ao usuário.</p>
       <p class="hidden-xs">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
       <h3>Produtividade</h3>
       <p class="description">Aumento de produtividade.</p>
       <p class="description">Informações claras e confiáveis de fácil acesso.</p>
       <p class="description">Diversidade de fornecedores e materiais.</p>
       <p class="description">Relatórios customizáveis.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
       <h3>Segurança e transparência</h3>
       <p class="description">Rastreabilidade e Histórico de processos.</p>
       <p class="description">Transparência e ética em processos.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
       <h3>Suporte</h3>
       <p class="description">Equipe de suporte ao usuário capacitada e pronto para auxiliar.</p>
       <p class="description">Equipe médica multidisciplinar.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group" id="solution">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="col-sm-3 img">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/InpartSaude.png" alt="Logo Inpart Saúde">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 img">
        <img  src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/QLikView.png" alt="QLikView">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 img">
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/InpartSaudeBI.png" alt="Inpart Saúde B.I.">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 img">
        <img  src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/InpartSaudeBI.jpg" alt="Inpart Saúde">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group" id="contact">
   <div class="container">
    <h4 class="title">Mantenha contato!</h4>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h2>Entre em contato diretamente conosco através do e-mail de atendimento da Inpart Saúde.</h2>
      <p>
       (xx) xxxx-xxxx
       <a href="mailto:xxx@xxx.com.br">xxx@xxx.com.br</a>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div><!--/#wrap -->
 <div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
   <p class="pull-right">
    Copyright © 2017 Inpart Saúde | 
    <a href="">Termos de serviço</a> | 
    <a href="">Políticas de privacidade</a>
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Só uma curiosidade: por que usar o IE 7?

Comment: Sistema legado que só funciona no IE-7 e não posso modificar no momento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou ser sincero, IE-7 está bem defasado, se fosse IE-8 ainda daria pra dizer algo, pois é capaz de encontrar usuários de WinXP e WinVista, apesar de geralmente usarem navegadores alternativos ou atualizarem pro IE8.

Bootstrap requer no minimo o IE8 e mesmo assim, nem o 8 nem o 9 suportam tudo, é bem provável que algumas coisas do seu projeto simplesmente não funcione, por mais que você tente.

O **fontawesome4** também não é suportado pelo IE-7 como explicado em http://fontawesome.io/get-started/, você pode experimentar o 3.2.1: http://fontawesome.io/3.2.1/get-started/#need-ie7, então depois de baixar os arquivos o teu HTML deve ficar semelhante a isto:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--[if IE 7]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Se ainda quiser insistir no IE-7 você pode usar responsividade e alguns outros recursos os seguintes *"polyfills"*:

- https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv
- https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Se baixar eles adicione assim (irá só funcionar em navegadores inferiores ao IE9):

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Se quiser usar CDNs:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou tentar essas alternativas vlw

Comment: @CaiqueRomero tenha em mente que você escolheu tecnologia super novas para usar em ambientes obsoletos, não espere milagres, o que você pode fazer é criar páginas mais estáticas que funcionem em navegadores antigos e com menos efeitos, ainda sim bonitos.